# List Iteration to Create Custom List in C#(Linq)

Tags: c#, list, linq, foreach

I have one List and from the List I have to Create new List with custom Property that are added in `HistoryItem2` class. In the HistoryItem2 Class the `Level` property is I want to add int value based on its loop index.

**HistoryItem.cs**

```
public class HistoryItem
    {
        public string HistoryName { get; set; }

        public List<HistoryItem> HistoryCollection { get; set; }

        public HistoryItem()
        {
            HistoryCollection = new List<HistoryItem>();
        }
    }
```

**HistoryItem2.cs**

```
public class HistoryItem2
    {
        public List<HistoryItem> historyItems { get; set; }
        public int Level { get; set; }
        public bool flag {get; set;}

        public HistoryItem2() {
            historyItems = new List<HistoryItem>();
        }

        public HistoryItem2(List<HistoryItem> historyItems, int level, bool flag)
        {
            this.historyItems = historyItems;
            this.Level = level;
            this.flag = flag;
        }
    }
```

I try so much thing but nothing is work for me.

**Edit :**

As see in this screen shot :

[image]

I want to set Level base on it's inside List.

Exmp : if List inside List inside List than and than it's level is `2`.

Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: You mean you want to copy the old items of type `HistoryItem` into new ones of type `HistoryItem2` and set the `Level` of the new ones to their index in the old list? And what about the `flag`?

Comment: @RenéVogt yes that right and all `flag` is initial to `false`.

Comment: Please clarify your problem.

Comment: HistoryItem2 should have a list of HistoryItem2's not HistoryItem right? Or how would you set the level > 0

Comment: `HistoryItem2` I have list of `HistoryItem` and in `HistoryItem2` i have to set `level` and `flag`.

Comment: But than if you are beyond level 0 how would you see it in the data structure since children don't have the level property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is a multi level list.

For that you don't need 2 different classes, one is sufficient. Here is one to help you get started.

```
public class HistoryItem
{
    public HistoryItem this[int i]
    {
        get => Children[i];
        set => Children[i] = value;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Level { get; private set; }

    private HistoryItem _parent;
    public HistoryItem Parent {
        get => _parent;
        set
        {
            if (value == null)
            {
                Level = 0;
                _parent = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Level = value.Level + 1;
                _parent = value;
            }
        }
    }

    public IList<HistoryItem> Children { get; set; }

    public HistoryItem()
    {
        Name = "Parent";
        Level = 0;
        Parent = null;
        Children = new List<HistoryItem>();
    }

    public HistoryItem(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        Level = 0;
        Parent = null;
        Children = new List<HistoryItem>();
    }

    public HistoryItem(HistoryItem parent)
    {
        Name = "Child";
        Level = parent.Level + 1;
        Parent = parent;
        Children = new List<HistoryItem>();
    }

    public HistoryItem(string name, HistoryItem parent)
    {
        Name = name;
        Level = parent.Level + 1;
        Parent = parent;
        Children = new List<HistoryItem>();
    }

    public void AddChild()
    {
        Children.Add(new HistoryItem("Child", this));
    }

    public void AddChild(string name)
    {
        Children.Add(new HistoryItem(name, this));
    }

    #region Overrides of Object

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"{Name} : Level: {Level}";
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Using this class is very simple. You create parent classes like so:

```
var parent1 = new HistoryItem("Parent One");
```

and add children in 2 ways, but the second way is preferred and recommended.

```
parent1.Children.Add(new HistoryItem("Child 1", parent1));
parent1.AddChild("Child 2");
```

Adding sub-children can be done like this:

```
parent1[0].AddChild("Sub-Child 1");
parent1[0].AddChild("Sub-Child 2");
```

And to change the parent of a subchild (can also make it top-level item if you set it to null) can be done like this:

```
parent1[0][0].Parent = parent1;
```

that will change the parent of the subchild1 from child1 to parent, which will in turn change it's level from 2 to 1.

Here is a dotnet fiddle to better see what's going on: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tIF1Xg

This code probably should not be used as final. Instead of a List you're better off creating your own collection and using that.

[image: Debugger View]